# How to get background-img through https in Moodle 2.6 with essential theme?

Tags: php, css, https, moodle

I set login via https but my background image are passed through http - I get warning about mixed content.
Does anyone have idea how to make it work?

I use Moodle 2.6.2 with Essential theme 2.7.

Comment: On my knows, no way to avoid it if you really are logged from https and have http queries. Maybe you can use a CDN in https but I don't know, I never deal with this kind of warnings

Comment: It would be awful bug... I have everything I need hosted locally - no way to force it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found resolution. Its so simple... Using user defined bg images resolves it. Until now I used default one. Silly me, it was so simple...

FYI - I think the cause of this issue is function defined in essential theme's lib.php - `theme_essential_set_pagebackground()`